# Displaying figures one after another using PyScript

Tags: html, pyscript

I am a newbie with PyScript.

The following code correctly prints a single plot on the browser.

```
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.css" />
<script defer src="https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.js"></script>

<pre>
<py-env>
    - numpy
    - matplotlib
</py-env>
        </pre>

</head>
<body>

<div id="matplotlib-lineplot">

    <pre>
<py-script output="matplotlib-lineplot" >
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
year_1 = [2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021]
population_1 = np.random.randint(20,size=6)
plt.plot(year_1, population_1, marker='o', linestyle='--', color='g', label='Country 1')
plt.xlabel('Year')
plt.ylabel('Population (M)')
plt.title('Year vs Population')
plt.legend(loc='lower right')
fig

</py-script>
        </pre>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I would like to extend this to printing 20 plots one after another in a loop and then stop at the final plot. For this I am trying:

```
<html>
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.css" />
<script defer src="https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.js"></script>

<pre>
<py-env>
    - numpy
    - matplotlib
</py-env>
        </pre>

</head>
<body>

<div id="matplotlib-lineplot">

    <pre>
<py-script output="matplotlib-lineplot" >
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

for step in range(20):

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    year_1 = [2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021]
    population_1 = np.random.randint(20,size=6)
    plt.plot(year_1, population_1, marker='o', linestyle='--', color='g', label='Country 1')
    plt.xlabel('Year')
    plt.ylabel('Population (M)')
    plt.title('Year vs Population')
    plt.legend(loc='lower right')
    fig

</py-script>
        </pre>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Which prints nothing. How would go about this?

I have also tried replacing `fig` with `plt.show()`, which also shows nothing.
I believe an alternative is to use `IPython.display()` but importing IPython throws an error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'termios' )` on my mac.

EDIT: After looking into the official docs I realised I was using an outdated way for printing. So I updated to:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/latest/pyscript.css" />
<script defer src="https://pyscript.net/latest/pyscript.js"></script>

<py-config>
  packages = ["matplotlib", "numpy"]

</py-config>
</head>
<body>


<py-script>
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import time

for step in range(20):

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    year_1 = [2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021]
    population_1 = np.random.randint(20,size=6)
    plt.plot(year_1, population_1, marker='o', linestyle='--', color='g', label='Country 1')
    plt.xlabel('Year')
    plt.ylabel('Population (M)')
    plt.title('Year vs Population')
    plt.legend(loc='lower right')
    display(fig, target="graph-area", append=False)
    time.sleep(1)
    plt.clf()

</py-script>

<div id="graph-area"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

But this prints a single figure

Comment: No, I would like figures appearing one after the other in the same position. like a video

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue in your final block of code (following EDIT) is the use of `time.sleep()`, which essentially instructs the operating system to leave the current thread alone for the given number of seconds, and resume execution of it at a later point. However, the browser is inherently a single-thread-per-tab environment* - there is no "other thread" to come back and "wake up" the current thread. So your execution is stuck at the first call of `time.sleep`.

(*This is true in the current version of PyScript (2023.03.1) - in a future release, PyScript will have the option to run in Web Worker thread, in a way which allows for blocking operations like this.)

To fix your issue, use a coroutine with `asyncio.sleep` like so:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import asyncio

async def showPlots():
    for step in range(20):
        fig, ax = plt.subplots()
        year_1 = [2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021]
        population_1 = np.random.randint(20,size=6)
        plt.plot(year_1, population_1, marker='o', linestyle='--', color='g', label='Country 1')
        plt.xlabel('Year')
        plt.ylabel('Population (M)')
        plt.title('Year vs Population')
        plt.legend(loc='lower right')
        display(fig, target="graph-area", append=False)
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        plt.clf()
    
asyncio.ensure_future(showPlots())
```